# Create an iOS machine learning application to predict objects using python and opencv

Tags: python, ios, opencv, coreml

I want to make an iOS app with the same usage at this website:
https://luigi-pathology.com/

In my case, the app will allow people to upload a photo of an object, and the app will tell them what kind of object is it (using machine learning, I already have the weight for the model, so the app just need to use it to predict the result, no need to train).

I already have the code in Python and Open CV to get image from a computer's directory and predict what kind of objects are in the image. But I don't know how to turn in into mobile app. When I looked up, seem like I cannot use Python in this case. So should I change everything to core ML? Or are there any way to maintain Python?

Comment: Core ML is worth the extra effort especially considering create ML was launched with MacOS Mojave which will enable you to create ML Models rather easily. Here is the link to Apples Introduction video of Create ML: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/703/

Comment: What sort of Python code do you have? Is it a model trained with Keras or TensorFlow? If so, you can use coremltools or tf-coreml to convert it to a Core ML model.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations. But how about openCV? Can I use it in ios app? Because my app will not predict the full image but it has to do circle detection first and then classify the circular objects in the image.